# ios swift FBSDKShareKit Publish (Share) content without ShareDialog view controller

Tags: swift, fbsdksharekit

i want to put function with "sharing facebook" when "user start live"

[image]

if that Fb Button is on then user touches that Live Button,
the content will publish on user's timeline on facebook automatically, then start "Live Broadcasting"

**so the ShareDialog will not be present up.
but if ShareDialog should be presented for permission,
i want to  do it when user touches that fb button.**

======== ref

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios

```
        var content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = URL.init(string: "https://www~")
        content.hashtag = FBSDKHashtag(string: "#ABCDE")
        //        content.contentTitle = self.broadcastingInfo.title ?? ""
        //        content.imageURL = self.broadcastingInfo.image
    
        //        var shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        //        shareDialog.shareContent = content
        //        shareDialog.mode = .native
        //        try shareDialog.show()
        //        do not want shareDialog


    
        FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: content, delegate: self) 
        // error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)
```